# MATLAB 3D data simple visualization

Tags: matlab, 3d, visualization

I would like to produce following 3D visualization in MATLAB:

[image]

```
mydata = rand(100,100,100);
```

How may I do it for `mydata`?

Comment: Its not even very clear what we see in the picture.......

Comment: @AnderBiguri It is a view of a 3D random array (not exactly `rand`, but similar).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
figure
volshow(mydata)
```

or

```
volumeViewer(mydata)
```

Comment: Future visitors should note use of  [`volshow`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/volshow.html) requires the **Image Processing Toolbox** and was introduced in **R2019a**.  The [`volumeViewer`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/volumeviewer-app.html) was introduced in **R2017a**. (+1) for multiple solutions.